# What does raw_spinlock mean?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, synchronization, kernel, spinlock

I was studying the `raw_spinlock` struct, which is in [`/usr/src/linux/include/linux/spinlock_types.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock_types.h#L20):

```c
typedef struct raw_spinlock {
        arch_spinlock_t raw_lock;
#ifdef CONFIG_GENERIC_LOCKBREAK
        unsigned int break_lock;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK
        unsigned int magic, owner_cpu;
        void *owner;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC
        struct lockdep_map dep_map;
#endif
} raw_spinlock_t;
```

I think `raw_lock` is for a lock which is dependent on an architecture and `dep_map` is a kind of data structure to avoid deadlocks, but what do `break_lock`, `magic`, `owner_cpu`, and `*owner` mean?

Comment: Please format your question to increase the chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

### `spinlock`

`spinlock` is public API for spinlocks in kernel code.

See [`Documentation/locking/spinlocks.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/locking/spinlocks.txt).

### `raw_spinlock`

`raw_spinlock` is actual implementation of normal spinlocks. On not-RT kernels, `spinlock` is just a wrapper for `raw_spinlock`. On RT kernels, `spinlock` doesn't always use `raw_spinlock`.

See [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/146861/) on LWN.

### `arch_spinlock`

`arch_spinlock` is platform-specific part of spinlock implementation. `raw_spinlock` is generally platform-independent and delegates low-level operations to `arch_spinlock`.

### `lockdep_map`

`lockdep_map` is a dependency map for locking correctness validator.

See [`Documentation/locking/lockdep-design.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/locking/lockdep-design.txt).

### `break_lock`

On SMP kernels, when `spin_lock()` on one CPU starts looping while the lock is held on another CPU, it sets this flag to `1`. Another CPU that holds the lock can periodically check this flag using `spin_is_contended()` and then call `spin_unlock()`.

This allows to archive two goals at the same time:

- avoid frequent locking/unlocking;
- avoid holding lock for a long time, preventing others to acquire the lock.

See also [this article](http://www.joelfernandes.org/linuxinternals/2014/05/07/spinlock-implementation-in-linux-kernel.html).

### `magic`, `owner`, `owner_cpu`

These fields are enabled when `CONFIG_SPINLOCK_DEBUG` is set and help to detect common bugs:

- `magic` is set to some randomly choosen constant when spinlock is created (`SPINLOCK_MAGIC` which is `0xdead4ead`)
- `owner` is set to current process in `spin_lock()`;
- `owner_cpu` is set to current CPU id in `spin_lock()`.

`spin_unlock()` checks that it is called when current process and CPU are the same as they were when `spin_lock()` was called.

`spin_lock()` checks that `magic` is equal to `SPINLOCK_MAGIC` to ensure that caller passed a pointer to correctly initialized spinlock and (hopefully) no memory corruption occurred.

See [`kernel/locking/spinlock_debug.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/locking/spinlock_debug.c).